# Why do the panels disappear when i press UP?

Tags: java, swing, applet, actionlistener

This is my code for a game im making. At the moment im not worried about how the game functions I've been more so worried about the fact that each time I hit the UP button the panels  disappear and sometimes when i hit the LEFT button as well. Is there an explanation to this can anyone help me understand why this happens?? I have a feeling it has something to do with my if statements but im not really sure. also, im messing around with the key listener and if you could give me some advice on key listeners like some dos and donts I really appreciate the help!!

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.applet.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import java.awt.*;


  public class Game extends Applet implements ActionListener,KeyListener {
     Image image;
     MediaTracker tr;
     JLabel label,computerLabel;
     JPanel panel,computerPanel;
     Button start,up,down;
     Label result;
     Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(50,50);

     int x = 0;
     int y = 0;
     int w = 100;
     int q = 100;
     int WIDTH = 50;
     int HEIGHT = 50;
     //Player Integers
     int zeroPosX,zeroPosY,xLeft,xUp;
     //Computer integers
     int compZeroPosX,compZeroPosY,compXLeft,compXUp;

     //--------------------------------------
     public void init()   {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        start = new Button("Start");
        up = new Button("UP");
        down = new Button("LEFT");
     //PlayerPiece stuff    
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("playerpiece.png");      
        label = new JLabel(icon);
        panel = new JPanel();

        label.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setPreferredSize(SIZE);
     //ComputerPiece Stuff
        ImageIcon computerIcon = new ImageIcon("computerPiece.png");
        computerPanel = new JPanel();
        computerLabel = new JLabel(computerIcon);

        computerLabel.setVisible(true);
        computerPanel.add(computerLabel);
        computerPanel.setPreferredSize(SIZE);

     //===============================================     

        result = new Label("=========");
        addKeyListener(this);

        setSize(650,650);

        up.addActionListener(this);
        down.addActionListener(this);
        start.addActionListener(this);

        label.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        label.setLocation(0,0);

        add(computerPanel);
        add(panel);
        add(start);
        add(up);
        add(down);
        add(result);


        }

     //--------------------------------------  
        public void paint(Graphics g)  {


           Graphics2D firstLayer = (Graphics2D)g;
           Graphics2D secondLayer = (Graphics2D)g;
           Graphics2D thirdLayer = (Graphics2D)g;


        secondLayer.setColor(Color.BLACK);


           for(x=100; x<=500; x+=100) 
               for(y=100; y <=500; y+=100)
               {

               firstLayer.fillRect(x,y,WIDTH,HEIGHT);


               }
           for(w=150; w<=500; w+=100) 
               for(q=150; q <=500; q+=100)
                  {

               secondLayer.fillRect(w,q,WIDTH,HEIGHT);


               }





           }
        //--------------------------------------
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)   {

           int [] range = {50,0,0,0,0};
           int selection = (int)Math.random()*5 ;


        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        //PlayerPositioning
            zeroPosX = panel.getX();
            zeroPosY = panel.getY();
            xLeft = zeroPosX - 50;
            xUp = zeroPosY - 50;  
        //ComputerPositioning
            compZeroPosX = computerPanel.getX();
            compZeroPosY = computerPanel.getY();
            compXLeft = compZeroPosX - range[selection];
            compXUp = compZeroPosY - range[selection];
        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    


            Button user = (Button)ae.getSource();




        //Starting the game
        if(user.getLabel() == "Start")   {
            result.setText("=========");
        //playersetup
            label.setLocation(0,0);
            panel.setLocation(300,500);
        //============================
        //npc setup
            computerLabel.setLocation(0,0);
            computerPanel.setLocation(500,300);


         }



           if(compZeroPosX >= 150)    {
              if(compZeroPosY >= 150)    {
                 if(zeroPosX >= 150)       {
                   if(zeroPosY >=150)         {  


                      if(user.getLabel() == "UP")   {
                        panel.setLocation(zeroPosX,xUp);

                        }
                        else     
                          computerPanel.setLocation(compZeroPosX,compXUp);




                      if(user.getLabel() == "LEFT") {
                         panel.setLocation(xLeft,zeroPosY);

                      }

                      else      
                         computerPanel.setLocation(compXLeft,compZeroPosY);

                       if(panel.getX() < 150) 
                          result.setText("GAME-OVER");


                       if(panel.getY() < 150)
                          result.setText("GAME-OVER");

                       }
                 }      
                 }
              }  
           }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent kp) {
           int keycode = kp.getKeyCode();

              switch (keycode)  {
                 case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                 panel.setLocation(xLeft,zeroPosY);
                 break;
                 }





        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent kr)   {

        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent kt)   {

        }

       }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issues and suggestions:

1. You're mixing AWT (e.g., Applet, Button, Label) with Swing (e.g., JPanel, JLabel) dangerously and without need. Stick with Swing and get rid of all vestiges of AWT.
2. You're painting directly in a top-level window, here the Applet, a dangerous thing to do. Don't. Follow the Swing graphics tutorials and do your drawing in a JPanel's paintComponent method.
3. You're not calling the super method within your painting method override, another dangerous thing to do, and another indication that you're trying to do this without reading the important relevant tutorials.
4. Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two object references are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.
5. You're trying to directly set the location of a component such as a JPanel without regard for the layout managers. Don't do this. Instead move logical (non-component) entities and display the movement in your graphics.

You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Later we can talk why you should avoid applets of all flavors...

Myself, I'd move ImageIcons around a grid of JLabels and not directly use a painting method at all. For example,

[image: Example program animation]

To see, run the following code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game2 extends JPanel {
    private static final String CPU_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/"
            + "Gorilla-thinclient.svg/50px-Gorilla-thinclient.svg.png";
    private static final String PERSON_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/"
            + "Emblem-person-blue.svg/50px-Emblem-person-blue.svg.png";
    private static final int SQR_WIDTH = 50;
    private static final int SIDES = 10;
    private static final Dimension SQR_SIZE = new Dimension(SQR_WIDTH, SQR_WIDTH);
    private static final Color DARK = new Color(149, 69, 53);
    private static final Color LIGHT = new Color(240, 220, 130);
    private JLabel[][] labelGrid = new JLabel[SIDES][SIDES];
    private Icon playerIcon;
    private Icon computerIcon;

    public Game2() throws IOException {
        // would use images instead
        playerIcon = createIcon(PERSON_PATH);
        computerIcon = createIcon(CPU_PATH);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new StartAction("Start", KeyEvent.VK_S)));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new UpAction("Up", KeyEvent.VK_U)));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new LeftAction("Left", KeyEvent.VK_L)));

        JPanel gameBrd = new JPanel(new GridLayout(SIDES, SIDES));
        gameBrd.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        for (int i = 0; i < labelGrid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < labelGrid[i].length; j++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel();
                label.setPreferredSize(SQR_SIZE);
                label.setOpaque(true);
                Color c = i % 2 == j % 2 ? DARK : LIGHT;
                label.setBackground(c);
                gameBrd.add(label);
                labelGrid[i][j] = label;
            }
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(gameBrd);

        // random placement, just for example
        labelGrid[4][4].setIcon(computerIcon);
        labelGrid[5][5].setIcon(playerIcon);
    }

    private Icon createIcon(String path) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
        return new ImageIcon(img);        
    }

    private abstract class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
        public MyAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }
    }

    private class StartAction extends MyAction {
        public StartAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO start game code

        }
    }

    // move all icons up
    private class UpAction extends MyAction {
        public UpAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // collection to hold label that needs to be moved
            Map<JLabel, Icon> labelMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < labelGrid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < labelGrid[i].length; j++) {
                    Icon icon = labelGrid[i][j].getIcon();
                    if (icon != null) {
                        int newI = i == 0 ? labelGrid.length - 1 : i - 1;
                        labelGrid[i][j].setIcon(null);
                        labelMap.put(labelGrid[newI][j], icon);
                    }
                }
            }

            // move the icon after the iteration complete so as not to move it twice
            for (JLabel label : labelMap.keySet()) {
                label.setIcon(labelMap.get(label));
            }
        }
    }

    // move all icons left
    private class LeftAction extends MyAction {
        public LeftAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Map<JLabel, Icon> labelMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < labelGrid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < labelGrid[i].length; j++) {
                    Icon icon = labelGrid[i][j].getIcon();
                    if (icon != null) {
                        int newJ = j == 0 ? labelGrid[i].length - 1 : j - 1;
                        labelGrid[i][j].setIcon(null);
                        labelMap.put(labelGrid[i][newJ], icon);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (JLabel label : labelMap.keySet()) {
                label.setIcon(labelMap.get(label));
            }
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Game2 mainPanel = null;
        try {
            mainPanel = new Game2();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so using an applet is problematic in and of itself, i think i should be able to transfer the code and make it work by using Swing components, but for the time being ill get to work on it and hope it works out in the end.

Comment: I would love to do what you just did BUT im still learning and there's a lot in that code that i still have yet to learn about so please understand that im doing this based on how much I know and based on what im capable of doing, but I really appreciate the advice and help, thank you!